# Vb.net want to use Dictionary like hashtable in perl

Tags: vb.net, perl, dictionary, key, hashtable

I have following code in perl, that generates random values until the amount of values is reached.
The Hashtable always store the random values at the same "place", so the hashtable has the right size when engough values are stored

```
while ( (keys( %unique_regex )) <= $amount_regex){
    $unique_regex{ $pass->randregex($regex) } = '1';
}
```

Now I want to do the same in vb.net with a dictionary, but i have to set the key, so the values are more than once in my hashtable/dict.

```
 Dim myDict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
 myDict.Add(0, CStr(Math.Round((((Rnd() Mod 3) * ((input_zufallszahl_obergrenze_1.Value) - input_zufallszahl_untergrenze_1.Value)) + ((input_zufallszahl_untergrenze_1.Value))), 0)))


 Dim tmphashcounter As Integer = 1
 While (myDict.Count <= array_integerzahlen.GetLength(0))

     myDict.Add(tmphashcounter, CStr(Math.Round((((Rnd() Mod 3) * ((input_zufallszahl_obergrenze_1.Value) - input_zufallszahl_untergrenze_1.Value)) + ((input_zufallszahl_untergrenze_1.Value))), 0)))
     tmphashcounter = tmphashcounter + 1

 End While
```

Comment: It would be very helpful for non-German people if you’d take the care of translating your code to proper English before posting it here. In fact, this is one of the reasons why code should be *exclusively* written in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should think that the cognate would be like this:

```
While myDict.Count <= array_integerzahlen.GetLength(0)
    randRegex = pass.randRegex( regex )
    If Not myDict.ContainsKey( randRegex )
        myDict.Add( randRegex, 1 )
    End If
End While
```

Of course, since you indicate that it's .NET, you simply have to use the indexing property. I should think that this might work:

```
While myDict.Count <= array_integerzahlen.GetLength(0)
    myDict( pass.randRegex( regex )) = True
End While
```

Comment: `GetLength(0)` => `Length`. Also, it’s weird that this field should be an array when it isn’t in the Perl code but this isn’t the only thing that’s weird in this code.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET you wouldn’t use a dictionary for this, you’d use a `HashSet`:

```
Dim mySet As New HashSet(Of Integer)()
Dim lower = input_zufallszahl_untergrenze_1.Value
Dim upper = input_zufallszahl_obergrenze_1.Value
Dim rng As New Random()

Do While mySet.Count < DesiredSize
    mySet.Add(rng.Next(lower, upper))
Loop
```

Your random-number generation is also seriously flawed. Besides the obvious flaws (what’s `CStr` doing there?) you should probably eschew the use of `Rnd` in favour of a proper random-number generator, and generating numbers via `Mod 3` introduces a *heavy* bias in the random numbers – they are no longer even remotely uniformly distributed. This is what the [`Random.Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) method is there for.

Notice that the actual code for adding the random numbers is only three lines long – exactly like your Perl code.

Comment: what would be a better algorithm for a random value? mod 1337 ? or another high prime number?.

Comment: cstr converts the integer value into a string, because my dict wants a string-value :>

Comment: @Tyzak Mod is always bad due to the way it works. See my code for a better way. As for `CStr`, why do you want string values? Your original code is storing integers in the dictionary, and that sounds right. *Don’t* store numbers as strings. **`String` is for text data only.** Only convert data to string for the purpose of displaying it, and then as late as possible. Always do your calculations on the *real* type.

Comment: "Heavy bias"??? If a 32-bit number is returned, the odds are 1,431,655,766 : 1,431,655,765 : 1,431,655,765

Comment: @ikegami They aren’t. Classical PRNGs have known weaknesses in the distribution of their lower bits. The skew will be much more pronounced.